# imagejpeg output using variable value not working in PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
include('core/init.php');

$name = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `photo_urlpath` FROM photos ORDER BY `photo_id` DESC LIMIT 1"), 0);

        if($name == false){
            echo "Failed to open $name";
        } else {
            echo "Worked! <br>" . "$name";
        }

$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('upload/watermarkMQ.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50);

// Output and free memory
    imagejpeg($im, "wm_" . $name);
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

The mysql result returns the photo_urlpath and it works well as it echoes "Worked!" and then the name of the file.

The only thing that DOESN'T work is the
    imagejpeg($im, "wm_" . $name);

I would like to use the same filename but with wm_ before the original image name.
But using that code it doesn't output anything. WHEN I replace $name with something like 'test.jpg' IT DOES WORK and it outputs a nice wm_test.jpg file.

Aren't you able to use a variable as output filename?

Comment: imagejpeg() couldn't care less **HOW** you generate the filename it's using. it'll NEVER see `wm_ . $name`. it'll see `wm_foo` because the string building occured BEFORE imagejpeg()'s code ever got executed. You've probably got bad chars or otherwise invalid filename in your urlpath value, or the final full filename you're building is invalid. e.g. `wm_C:\blah\blah\blah\kittens.jpg`

Comment: Exactly the same thing happened to me. I hope we will find a solution soon.
[Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) PHP 5.3.3]

Comment: Perhaps not quite an answer, but I'd recommend looking at imagick if you can. It's a lot easier than gd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps in your case, but I was reading file names from a text file and each string variable that stored a path still had an end-of-line character at the end. I simply cut it off by using

`$fileName = substr($fileName, 0, -1);`

and now it works perfectly. I suggest you to check what the SQL query gives you back. There might be some special characters somewhere that you need to drop out.